# Error occurred while executing GetUsers Code: Authorization_RequestDenied Message: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-functions

I try to get users from AAD by an Azure Function (PowerShell) with managed identity.

This is my code:

```
Import-Module AzureAD -UseWindowsPowerShell
Connect-AzAccount -identity
$context = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Abstractions.AzureRmProfileProvider]::Instance.Profile.DefaultContext
$graphToken = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.AzureSession]::Instance.AuthenticationFactory.Authenticate($context.Account, $context.Environment, $context.Tenant.Id.ToString(), $null, [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.ShowDialog]::Never, $null, "https://graph.microsoft.com").AccessToken
$aadToken = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.AzureSession]::Instance.AuthenticationFactory.Authenticate($context.Account, $context.Environment, $context.Tenant.Id.ToString(), $null, [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.ShowDialog]::Never, $null, "https://graph.windows.net").AccessToken
$body = "Hi I'm $($context.Account.Id)"
Connect-AzureAD -AadAccessToken $aadToken -AccountId $context.Account.Id -TenantId $context.tenant.id
$allUsers = Get-AzureADUser -All $True
```

I give my managed identity this permissions:

[image]

This is the error:

> Error occurred while executing GetUsers Code:
> Authorization_RequestDenied Message: Insufficient privileges to
> complete the operation

Do I miss some permissions to read users from AAD?

[AAD accestoken](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsL9i.png)

Comment: Can you print $aadToken and decode it using https://jwt.ms/ and check if the roles are displayed?

Comment: If still the issue persists assign Directory Reader Role to the managed identity and try

Comment: The same script with the same permissions worked in my environment. Check **[this](https://i.imgur.com/7wkcJQi.png)**

Comment: But my question is to make it work with an managed identity from an Azure Function app. See for example this tutorial. https://github.com/brettmillerb/azureadFunction

Comment: I checked the $aadToken and decode it by jwt.ms. But which claim should show roles? I dont see something with roles.

Comment: Can you paste the screenshot?

Comment: What worked two years ago may not work today.  Most systems are moving from Windows Credentials to OAUTH2.  If the server switched from Windows Credentials to OAUTH2 code on the link will not work.

Comment: I just would like to get all AAD users from an Azure Function App in Powershell without user credentials. So the solution must be something with an managed identity or Azure App Registration. What is the best practice at this moment?

Comment: See printscreen in my post above with the aad access token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially I got the ***same error***:

[image]

I assigned below permissions to the managed identity:

[image]

The [**GitHub blog**](https://github.com/brettmillerb/azureadFunction#assign-user-administrator-role-to-identity-in-azuread) you are referring states that you have to assign User Administrator role to the managed identity.

Hence to resolve the error, assign active **User Administrator role to the managed identity**:

[image]

Now, when I executed the same script, **I got the list of users successfully:**

```
using namespace System.Net
# Input bindings are passed in via param block.
param($Request, $TriggerMetadata)
Import-Module AzureAD -UseWindowsPowerShell

Connect-AzAccount -Identity
$context = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Abstractions.AzureRmProfileProvider]::Instance.Profile.DefaultContext
$graphToken = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.AzureSession]::Instance.AuthenticationFactory.Authenticate($context.Account, $context.Environment, $context.Tenant.Id.ToString(), $null, [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.ShowDialog]::Never, $null, "https://graph.microsoft.com").AccessToken
$aadToken = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.AzureSession]::Instance.AuthenticationFactory.Authenticate($context.Account, $context.Environment, $context.Tenant.Id.ToString(), $null, [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.ShowDialog]::Never, $null, "https://graph.windows.net").AccessToken
$body = "Hi I'm $($context.Account.Id)"

Connect-AzureAD -AadAccessToken $aadToken -AccountId $context.Account.Id -TenantId $context.tenant.id
$allUsers = Get-AzureADUser -All $True
$allUsers
```

[image]

You can also modify the script to display the output in table format:

```
using namespace System.Net
# Input bindings are passed in via param block.
param($Request, $TriggerMetadata)
Import-Module AzureAD -UseWindowsPowerShell

Connect-AzAccount -Identity
$context = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Abstractions.AzureRmProfileProvider]::Instance.Profile.DefaultContext
$graphToken = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.AzureSession]::Instance.AuthenticationFactory.Authenticate($context.Account, $context.Environment, $context.Tenant.Id.ToString(), $null, [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.ShowDialog]::Never, $null, "https://graph.microsoft.com").AccessToken
$aadToken = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.AzureSession]::Instance.AuthenticationFactory.Authenticate($context.Account, $context.Environment, $context.Tenant.Id.ToString(), $null, [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.ShowDialog]::Never, $null, "https://graph.windows.net").AccessToken
$body = "Hi I'm $($context.Account.Id)"
Connect-AzureAD -AadAccessToken $aadToken -AccountId $context.Account.Id -TenantId $context.tenant.id

$allUsers = Get-AzureADUser -All $True
$allUsers | Format-Table -Property ObjectId, DisplayName, UserPrincipalName
$tableOutput = $allUsers | Format-Table -Property ObjectId, DisplayName, UserPrincipalName | Out-String
$tableOutput
```

[image]

**If still the issue persists,** try this command `Connect-AzAccount -Identity -AccountId XXX` (Pass the Application ID of the identity)